# Edit text is not editable in Android Pie 9.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view, android-keypad

Hello Everyone,
               I m having an issue with the `AppCompatEditText`. I have override an `AppCompatEditText` and add `Enter` button in keyboard (`setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO)`). This is working fine on all Android versions, expect on 9.0. Here is the code of my Class

```
 public class EditTextWithGOButton extends AppCompatEditText {

    private EditTextAction editTextAction;

    public interface EditTextAction {
        void onGoButtonClicked(String text);
    }

    public void setEditTextAction(EditTextAction editTextAction) {
        this.editTextAction = editTextAction;

    }

    public EditTextWithGOButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        changeImeOption();
    }

    public EditTextWithGOButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        changeImeOption();
    }

    public EditTextWithGOButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        changeImeOption();
    }

    private void changeImeOption() {
        this.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            if (editTextAction != null){

                editTextAction.onGoButtonClicked(getText().toString());

            }
        }
        // Returning false allows other listeners to react to the press.
        return false;

        // Handle all other keys in the default way
//        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

And My XML.

```
<com.app.common.views.EditTextWithGOButton
            android:id="@+id/edt_search_bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3.2"
    android:background="@drawable/search_edittext_rounded_corner_background"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:hint="@string/search_your_activity"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingTop="05dp"
            android:paddingBottom="05dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

I have tired to set it focus able manually. When I remove `this.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);` and `onKeyDown` listener, `AppCompatEditText` became editable , But keyboard won't pop up. I have tried `EditText` as well.But issue remain same. *Any Solution* ??

Comment: I tried your code and works fine on api 28, keyboard pops and able to write. What is the problem?

Comment: @underoid did u tried on Android Pie?

Comment: Yes it is Pie 9.0

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Do you reveal the solution for us, please.